# Proving partial order for a set

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

My question is:

Prove that if $R$ is a partial order for a set $A$ and if $zRx_1,x_1Rx_2,x_2Rx_3,\cdots,x_{n-1}Rx_n$ and $x_nRz$, then $z=x_1=x_2=x_3=\cdots=x_n$.

I am not too sure how to go about this but I am guessing I need to first show each part of the partial condition. Or should I just use the properties since it's assumed $R$ is a partial order? 
I am not too sure how to start off the proof. Can I only use the fact that it is antisymmetric to get z=x_1 and so forth.

Comment: Is your assumption assumed to be true for all $n$ or only for a fixed $n$?

Comment: @Crostul I'm not too sure this is all the statement says

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ R $ is a partial order, $R $ is transitive and antisymmetric:

Transitive: If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $xRz$ for any $x,y,z$

Antisymmetric: If $xRy$ and $yRz$, then $x=y$ for any $x,y$

OK, since $zRx_1$ and $x_1Rx_2$, by transitivity, $zRx_2$. Then, since $x_2Rx_3$, again by transitivity $zRx_3$, though notice we also get $x_1Rx_3$. Etc etc, so eventually you get $zRx_n$ ... But also $x_1Rx_n$, $x_2Rx_n$, etc etc.,  Finally, since $x_nRz$ we get $zRz$, ... but also $x_1Rz$, $x_2Rz$ etc. In sum, we have $zRx_i$ as well as $x_iRz$ for any $1 \leq i \leq n$. So, by antisymmetry, we have $z = x_i$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$, meaning they are all the same.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Honestly, thank you! So I guess it's just a matter of showing a lot of transitivity?

Comment: Yes, transitivity the whole way around, so they all end up standing in relation R to each other ... Which by antisymmetry means they are all the same.

Comment: How did you end up getting x1Rxn?

Comment: No, The result follows from transitivity and antisymmetry alone. Yes, it turns out that the objects in the cycle all stand in the relation R to themselves, but again that follows from transitivity, antisymmetry, and the fact that they are in a cycle. If they were not in a cycle, they might not stand in relation R to themselves. Indeed, partial orders need not be reflexive. A strict partial order, for example the strict subset relation, is in fact irreflexive.

Comment: Sorry I was confusing symmetry with reflexive.

Comment: You get $x_1Rx_3$ by transitivity from $x_1Rx_2$ and $x_2Rx_3$. Then combine that with $x3Rx_4$ to get $x_1Rx_4$ etc etc.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. eventually you get x1Rz. So I would have to do this for each case?

Comment: So it gets to a point where we get x1Rx_n-1 and x_n-1Rxn so x1Rxn. Then x1Rxn and xnRz so x1Rz

Comment: Exactly!  And the same goes for $x_2$, $x_3$, etc.

Comment: Okay got it. Then since I am writing a proof would I have to explicitly write this out for each x1,x2,x3,xn?

Comment: Well, you don't really know the value of $n$, so you will end up using ellipsis (...). In fact, $n$ might be just 1 for all we know, so to do this completely mathematically correct you would have to use expressions like 'take any $1 \leq i \leq n$

Comment: Hmm so can I just show it for like x1Rz and say similarly x2Rz,x3Rz,...,xn-1Rz, and xnRz

Comment: In fact, even if you did know $n$, you might not want to explicitly write out the whole sequence for each x ... What if n is really big?!  So, I would just say something like ' do this for all $x_i$ from 1 to $n$.

Comment: Exactly!  Hey, I have to go but I think you got it!

Comment: Okay I'll go with what I wrote. It's okay thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can straight-up apply the properties of $R$ being a partial order because that is given to you on the statement.  In particular you can use the transitivity of $R$ to show what you want.

Start by using transitivity to show that $zRx_k$ and $x_kRz $ and then use anti-simmetry to show they are equal.

Comment: Only the transitive property? I'm just not too sure where to start.

Comment: @Sam first transitivity; then anti-simmetry

Comment: The will I ever need to use the fact that R is reflexive?

Comment: @Sam reflexivity is not necessary for your proof

Comment: Okay I'm just a little confused. So let's say for the case of zRx_1 and x_1Rx_2 then since we know R is transitive we have zRx_2. But then how would this help for antisymmetry.

Comment: @sam keep your chain going to get also $x_2Rz $. Only then use anti-simmetry

Comment: I'm lost how that would work unless we use the fact that R is reflexive. Can you maybe write out a bit of what you mean so I can see what it is you are saying?

Answer (score 0):

We have: $z \le x_1 \le x_2 \le ...\le x_{n-1} \le x_n \le z$. Thus $z \le x_k, x_k \le z\implies z = x_k, k = 1, .., n$. This means:$x_1 = x_2 = ...= x_n = z$.

Comment: I'm looking more to writing a proof. I am not too sure how you got those inequalities form the assumptions.